# Android Bluetooth write() method

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I'm trying to create bluetooth application, using this tutorial:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html

There is class ConnectedThread:

```
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
        // member streams are final
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) { }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public void run() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  // buffer store for the stream
        int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

        // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity
                mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                        .sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /* Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device */
    public void write(byte[] bytes) {
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(bytes);
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }

    /* Call this from the main activity to shutdown the connection */
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }
}
```

Comment says I need to call write() method from main activity, but there is actually no instance of ConnectedThread class, it is just started from another class. How can I use this method?

EDIT1:

I see why I can't use it that way. 
It doesn't work, because ConnectedThread is defined and declared at the point in the program and when program leaves it, it no longer exists, right? So, should I define object of ConnectedThread visible in whole activity and just define it in Connect thread. Instead:

```
ConnectedThread mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(mmSocket);
mConnectedThread.start();
```

I could use:

```
mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(mmSocket); 
mConnectedThread.start();
```

Right?

Comment: What do you mean with "started from another class"?

Comment: Exactly like in this tutorial, which I'm using also:
http://www.egr.msu.edu/classes/ece480/capstone/spring14/group01/docs/appnote/Wirsing-SendingAndReceivingDataViaBluetoothWithAnAndroidDevice.pdf

Where ConnectedThread is started in ConnectThread. I'm sorry, if I mixed something up.
I'm not sure how am I suppose to send datas. Object of ConnectedThread class is created in ConnectThread class and there is called its method:
mConnectedThread.start();

Comment: So this is not possible?
`connectedThread = new ConnectedTread(...);
 connectedThread.run();
 connectedThread.write("your message");`

Comment: So this is how it is. I thought, that extends class with Thread makes somehow accessible from whole activity, like some kind of singleton, when it is started. I need to read more about this. Thanks!

Comment: I updeated a question. Does it have chance to work?

Comment: Try it out and see if it works.

Comment: I did it as in EDIT1 - put it in `onCreate()` and created method - click button and send data via bluetooth:
`String sequence = "1234";
mConnectedThread.write(sequence.getBytes());`
But everything I got is NullPointerException. Have I done it wrong?